# serializeBinary() not found using google-protobuf on nodejs

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers

I could really use some help.  I am trying to follow along on the google-protobuf example:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-protobuf

However, when I try this line of code:
// Serializes to a UInt8Array.
var bytes = message.serializeBinary();

I get a Type Error saying that serializeBinary is not a function.

Is there a different function, or something I am missing?  I could really use the help.

Best Regards,

Mike

Answer (score -1):

Is the problem solved now?
I had the same problem, until I realized maybe I wasn't creating a real proto object and that is why it cannot recognize serializeBinary() as a function.

True enough, my message was actually a JavaScript object.

So I had to build a proto object by following this article.
https://ednsquare.com/story/working-with-protocol-buffers-in-javascript------MaDIJH

Basically, you have to initialize your proto object and then add properties to it through the set methods. In this way, the proto object is properly built. And therefore, should have the serializeBinary() function.

Comment: Not worked event he website is down